# How to compare a string with a large command output in Robot Framework

Tags: unit-testing, testing, robotframework

I'm trying to compare the output of sslscan command with a list of ciphers to check that the endpoint is securized.
This is the code snippet I'm using:

```
*** Settings ***
    Library           OperatingSystem
    Library           Process
*** Variables ***
    ${endpoint}    myendpoint.com

*** Test Cases ***
    Check ciphers
        ${secure_ciphers} =    Create list    ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256    DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256    ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
        ${insecure_ciphers} =    Create list    ECDH    aNULL    eNULL    
        ${result} =    Run process    sslscan --no-cipher-details --no-compression --no-fallback --no-groups --no-heartbleed --no-colour ${endpoint}    shell=True
        Log    SSLScan Output: ${output}
        Check secureCiphers    ${result.output}    ${secure_ciphers}
        Check insecureCiphers    ${result.output}    ${insecure_ciphers}

*** Keywords ***
    Check Secure Ciphers
        [Arguments]    ${output}    ${secureCiphers}
        FOR    ${cipher}    IN    @{secureCiphers}
            Log    ${output}
            Should Contain    ${output}    ${cipher}
        END

    Check Insecure Ciphers
        [Arguments]    ${output}    ${insecureCiphers}
        FOR    ${cipher}    IN    @{insecureCiphers}
            Log    ${output}
            Should Not Contain    ${output}    ${cipher}
        END
```

However, I'm receiving the following output error:

```
Check ciphers                                                         | FAIL |
Resolving variable '${result.output}' failed: AttributeError: 'ExecutionResult' object has no attribute 'output'
```

The output of sslscan looks like:

```
Testing SSL server mydomain.com on port 443 using SNI name mydomain.com

  SSL/TLS Protocols:
SSLv2     disabled
SSLv3     disabled
TLSv1.0   disabled
TLSv1.1   disabled
TLSv1.2   enabled
TLSv1.3   enabled

  TLS renegotiation:
Session renegotiation not supported

  Supported Server Cipher(s):
Preferred TLSv1.3  128 bits  TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
Accepted  TLSv1.3  256 bits  TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Accepted  TLSv1.3  256 bits  TLS_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256
Preferred TLSv1.2  256 bits  ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
Accepted  TLSv1.2  256 bits  DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
Accepted  TLSv1.2  256 bits  ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305
Accepted  TLSv1.2  128 bits  ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
Accepted  TLSv1.2  128 bits  DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256

  SSL Certificate:
Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSXEncryption
RSA Key Strength:    2048

Subject:  *.etx-dev.ktc-int.net
Altnames: DNS:mydomain.com, DNS:*.mydomain.com
Issuer:   StackOverflow

Not valid before: Dec 18 11:52:04 2023 GMT
Not valid after:  Nov  9 11:52:04 2160 GMT
```

I assume that I'm not saving properly the command output. Which is the right way to save and and compare the output?

Answer (score 0):

Reading from [the documentation](https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/Process.html#Result%20object), the `Process` library returns a result object that contains the following attributes :

> - rc : Return code of the process as an integer.
> - stdout : Contents of the standard output stream.
> - stderr : Contents of the standard error stream.
> - stdout_path : Path where stdout was redirected or None if not    redirected.
> - stderr_path : Path where stderr was redirected or None if    not redirected.

In order to read from the output of the shell command, you can read from `${result.stdout}`. Note that it will be empty if your sub process execution fails, in which case information may be written in `${result.stderr}` instead